# Solving system of equations in rationals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Do there exist solutions to solve system of $n-2$ equations with $n-2$ variables where $n$ is fixed even integer and $a_i,b,c\in\mathbb{Q},i\in\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-5\}$
$$\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  a_{n-5}+b=\frac{{n\choose 2}}{n}\\
                  a_{n-6}+ba_{n-5}+c=\frac{{n\choose 3}}{n}\\
                  a_{n-7}+ba_{n-6}+ca_{n-5}=\frac{{n\choose 4}}{n}\\a_{n-8}+ba_{n-7}+ca_{n-6}=\frac{{n\choose 5}}{n}\\\vdots\\a_0+ba_1+ca_2=\frac{{n\choose n-3}}{n}\\ba_0+ca_1=\frac{{n\choose n-2}}{n}\\ca_0=\frac{{n\choose n-1}}{n}
                \end{array}
              \right.$$
    I stumbled upon this while solving some problem,I haven't worked with matrices in school and I couldn't find any material for solving system of equations,couldn't even find a good explanation for $2\times 2$ system by matrices.I can understand solution(google + wikipedia makes wonders),or if someone is to guide me how to begin I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Two words – [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_elimination).

Comment: What are the variables in this system?  Because if they are $b,c,a_0, \ldots, a_{n-5}$, then you don't even have a linear system.

Comment: @Hayden Yeah seems you're right,anyway fixing $b,c$ isn't a problem in my case,I'm mostly interested in finding does there exist solutions to those system with all variables $\in\mathbb{Q}$,than finding solutions might be nice